# How do i setup ECS autoscaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I'm using ECS through [ecs-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CLI.html) to deploy my API.

I start by launching a cluster of spot instances using this command :

```
sudo ecs-cli up --region MY REGION --keypair MY KEY PAIR --instance-type t2.micro --capability-iam --size 1 --cluster MY CLUSTER NAME --spot-price 0.01
```

Then, using the following docker-compose.yml and ecs-params.yml files :

```
version: '3'

services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ...etc

  api:
    image: myapithatusesselenium/myapithatusesselenium
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    links:
      - selenium
    ...etc
```

```
version: 1
task_definition:
  task_execution_role: ROLE ID
  services:
    selenium:
      cpu_shares: 600
      mem_limit: 700000000
    api:
      repository_credentials:
        credentials_parameter: REPO CREDENTIALS
      cpu_shares: 400
      mem_limit: 300000000
```

I'm deploying a service with a load balancer using this command :

```
sudo ecs-cli compose --file docker-compose.yml --ecs-params ecs-params.yml --project-name MY PROJECT NAME service up --cluster MY CLUSTER NAME --target-group-arn LOAD BALANCER RESSOURCE ID --container-name api --container-port 3000
```

So, When my API is under a lot of load (When it starts notifying me that the API is going down) I add additional instances by scaling using these commands:

```
# 1 - scale the number of ec2 instances in the cluster
sudo ecs-cli scale --size 3 --capability-iam
# 2 - scale the number of tasks
sudo ecs-cli compose --file docker-compose.yml --project-name MY PROJECT NAME service scale 3
```

As you can see the number of tasks and ec2 instances is the same because each container can handle a single task.

When there isn't a lot of load I reduce the size again.

What I need right now is a way to make this automatic (Auto scaling in and out). I can't figure out how to do that.

Thank you !

Comment: Check this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/powering-your-amazon-ecs-clusters-with-spot-fleet/#:~:text=Auto%20Scaling%20and%20Spot%20fleet,to%20help%20facilitate%20this%20scenario.  Currently, Spot fleet requests cannot be integrated directly with Auto Scaling policies as they can with Spot instance requests. However, the Spot fleet API does include an action called ModifySpotFleetRequest that can change the target capacity of your request

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy ECS-CLI doesn't use spot fleet it launches spot instances individually

Answer (score 0):

ECS doesn't nativly autoscaling.  You have to use the application autoscaling service for that.  You'll need to use the regular aws CLI and call register-scalable-target, and then create a scaling policy

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/application-autoscaling/register-scalable-target.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/application-autoscaling/put-scaling-policy.html

Comment: Can you give me an example ? I'm a bit confused as there are many ways to do a single thing in AWS.